# how to plot only specified y values only in y axis

Tags: jquery, graph, charts, flot

I am using jquery flot chart plugin to plot the chart. I want to plot a graph with specified y values, that means, want to display only specific y values only. is this possible?. Please help to find out the solution.

Comment: Could you post something that you've tried?

Comment: Do you mean, on the axis? Look at the `ticks` option. Do you mean the data points themselves? Then use a copy from your original data array where you remove the data points you don't want.

Comment: @Raidri thanx. it worked